# Central Limit Theorem - interval estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem

I'm rolling a regular dodecahedron (12-side die) 1200 times. I need to find an interval, in which the total count of prime-number results will lie with the probability of 95%. I have to use the Central Limit Theorem (CLT).

I'm not sure, how to use the CLT, but I have developed some way, how it could work. I'd like you to check it and tell me whether it is right, or what is wrong and how it should be. And also there are some question, I would like to ask.

My solution:

$n = 1200$ ...count of the rolls

Prime numbers in dodecahedron are 2,3,5,7,11, therefor probability $q$ of the rolling one of the prime numbers is $\frac {5}{12}$.

For Alternative distribution the mean equals to $q$ and the variance is $q(1-q)$. So we got:

$\mu = \frac {5}{12}$

$\sigma^2 = \frac {35}{144}$

Then as the CLT says, we can obtain an approximation for the distribution of this random variable $X$ by a normal distribution ($X_n$). This random variable will have parameters:

$EX = n \cdot \mu = 1200 \cdot \frac {5}{12} = 500$

$DX=n \cdot \sigma^2 = 1200 \cdot \frac {35}{144} $

And the random variable we are looking for is:
$X_n = \frac {X-EX}{\sqrt{DX}}$

I know, that I need it for the probability of 95%, so I look up for it in statistical tables for the quantile function of the standardized normal distribution and I find $\Phi^{-1}(0.950) = 1.645$, which is $X_n$.

$\frac {X-EX}{\sqrt{DX}} = 1.645$

And I solve this for $X-EX$

$X-EX = 1.645 \cdot \sqrt{DX} = 1.645 \cdot \sqrt{1200 \cdot \frac {35}{144} } = 28.09$.

With the probability of 95% the count of values with the prime numbers in 1200 rolls of the regular dodecahedron will be in the interval $ \left[EX-28 ... EX+28\right] $.

This, I believe, is not correct result. There must be some inequality, right? Which one and why? I mean... the propability is 95% and more, or 95% and less?

And the second question is: How to round the distance between EX and X? I mean... all down, or .4 down, .5 up? In Chebyshev's inequality that is clear, because of the inequality in the formula. Here I'm confused.

And also I would like to know something more about the role of the standardization in here, if there is any. Because the tables are called "quantile function of the **standardized** normal distribution", $X_n$ should actually be standardized, whatever it means.

Comment: The chance of observing a prime in one roll of this die, *assuming* it is labeled with the numbers $1$ through $12$, is $6/12=1/2$. This makes the question equivalent to asking for a 95% interval for the number of heads in $1200$ flips of a fair coin--and that's a problem you (presumably) have answered before.

Comment: @whuber The task says we are looking for probability of rolling 2,3,5,7 and 11, so the person who wrote this task might not assume number one as a prime number. Can you at least tell me whether my procedure of solving this is correct?

Comment: I don't think anybody includes $1$ as a prime: I simply miscounted! Although you do most of the calculations needed to solve this problem, I think you go astray around the point you introduce "$X_n$", because it is unnecessary and proves to be a distraction. Once you determine that $X$ has a mean of $500$ and variance of $3500/12$ (which is far greater than $0.243$, by the way), and you choose to approximate its distribution with a Normal distribution, you have everything you need to answer this question.

Comment: What you require is a two-sided confidence interval centered around the mean, an interval that must contain $95$% of the total probability mass. So it must leave outside $2.5$% from one side, and $2.5$% from the other side. And correct your variance calculation.

Comment: @Alecos Because no data are used in computing this interval, *it is not a confidence interval.*  It might usefully be characterized as a prediction interval (based on no data!).

Comment: @whuber Indeed. But back in 2013, I wasn't knowledgeable enough to understand the distinction.